# How to filter for dates range in timeseries or dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, alpha-vantage

Still a newbie with Python just trying to learn this stuff. Appreciate any help.

Right now when I connect to Alpha Vantage I get the full range of data for all the dates and it looks like this
[image]

I found some good sources for guides, but I keep getting empty dataframes or errors
[image]

This is how the code looks so far

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import numpy as np

stock_ticker = 'SPY'
api_key = open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/key').read()

ts = TimeSeries (key=api_key, output_format = "pandas")
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=stock_ticker, outputsize ='full')
#data_date_changed = data[:'2019-11-29']

data = pd.DataFrame(data_daily)

df.loc[datetime.date(year=2014,month=1,day=1):datetime.date(year=2015,month=2,day=1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this is

```
stock_ticker = 'SPY'
api_key = 'apikeyddddd'

ts = TimeSeries (key=api_key, output_format = "pandas")
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=stock_ticker, outputsize ='full')

test = data_daily[(data_daily.index > '2014-01-01') & (data_daily.index <= '2017-08-15')]

print(data_daily)
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime 
df.loc[datetime.date(year=2014,month=1,day=1):datetime.date(year=2014,month=2,day=1)]
```

In my experience, you can't pass a simple string inside `loc`, needs to be a datetime object.

Comment: How do I set that up so I can print out the results?  I tried to do filter = df.loc[datetime.date(year=2014,month=1,day=1):datetime.date(year=2014,month=2,day=1)] and it still printed out empty dataframe

Comment: Maybe that is because you don't have any date within that range. Try increasing the range

Comment: The dates in the dataframe are from 1999 to 2020. The dates are stored in the index, does that effect the code for df.loc?